# Merge data frame onto another but start from a certain row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large data frame which has reading data in it, and I want to merge another `dataframe` of the same structure but a subset of columns and far fewer rows.

The idea is that the large `dataframe` represents almost all of what I want but I will have a set of readings that might start at any point (row) in the larger frame that I need to drop the columns onto.

As an example if the large data frame looked similar to this and had 5 rows:

```
   A  B
0  1  11
1  2  12
2  3  13
3  4  14
4  5  15
```

The smaller `dataframe` looks like the following and has fewer rows and only one of the columns:

```
   B
0  1000
1  2000
```

When I merge I want to have a `dataframe` that contains all the row count of the first, but I want to "overlay" the second frame onto it from a row I specify, so for example from row 2, so I would expect then for the new `dataframe` to look like this:

```
   A  B
0  1  11
1  2  12
2  3  1000
3  4  2000
4  5  15
```

The end result is that the new `dataframe` is the same size as the first, but the value of column B has been updated, from a row I specify to the length of the second `dataframe` and only for the columns in the second data frame.

Comment: Please provide sample data in code.

Comment: I can provide a trimmed down example.

Comment: I have tried to create a simple example which shows more clearly what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

Let's say `df` is the bigger df and `df1` is the small one.

```
...
shift = 2
df1.index = df1.index + shift
df.update(df1)
```

Result:

```
   A       B
0  1    11.0
1  2    12.0
2  3  1000.0
3  4  2000.0
4  5    15.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to align your indexes first.  Pandas does most operations with intrinsic data alignment, therefore you can use this methodology to update your df1, dataframe:

```
df2.set_axis([2, 3]).combine_first(df1)
```

Output:

```
   A     B
0  1    11
1  2    12
2  3  1000
3  4  2000
4  5    15
```

Comment: Not really scalable as you would need to manually set all the ids every time.

Comment: You can use any method you want to set your indexes, the key is to align your indexes with your original dataframe values you want to change/update.